# javax.servlet .lastUpdated issue

Tags: java, maven, servlets, pom.xml

I have the following dependencies in pom.xml:

```
  <properties>
      <javax.servlet.version>3.1.0</javax.servlet.version>
  </properties>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>${javax.servlet.version}</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
```

When I run `nvm clean install` in my project, in my `~/.m2/repository/javax/servlet/servlet-api/3.1.0/` maven creates `servlet-api-3.1.0.jar.lastUpdated` and `servlet-api-3.1.0.pom.lastUpdated`

Why does maven create `servlet-api-3.1.0.jar.lastUpdated` instead of `servlet-api-3.1.0.jar` ?

Comment: Well, have you googled for `maven lastUpdated`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because download servlet-api-3.1.0.jar failed from network.
you can see the debug,and find wihch reason lead to download failed.

maven find jar process:
1.from your loacal responsitory (`.m2` dir)
2.if not found,will find from there（where your pom.xml setting）

```
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
        </snapshots>
        <id>public</id>
        <name>Public Repositories</name>
        <url>http://yourOwnRepository/nexus/content/repositories/thirdparty/</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```

3.if not found,will find from your maven settings.xml config

4.if not fond,will find from default maven repository